# Specific basis for the space of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Consider the space of symmetric matrices $symm(M)$ over reals of dimension $n \times n$. It is clear that there is a straightforward basis for this space where for any $i \ge j$ $M_{ij}(m,n) = 1$ if $m = i,j$ and $n = j,i$, otherwise 0 everywhere.

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

$$vec(M)\cdot vec(yy^T - zz^T) = 0 $$
where M is a full rank symmetric matrix, $y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Now, can we find $O(d^2)$ vectors in the orthogonal complement of $vec(M)$ such that they span the complement and each can be written as $vec(yy^T - zz^T)$?

In other words, is there a basis to the **orthogonal subspace** of $M$ such that every element is of the form $vec(yy^T - zz^T)$?

The basis above ${M_{ij}}$ has that desired form where the idea is to just consider extended vectors for $[1/2, 1]$ and $[1/2, -1]$. But this won't ensure why anu other vector has the desired form. Some idea on how to solve this would be useful.

Comment: Have you attempted to see what happens (entrywise) for $n=2$ (maybe a little particular case) or $n=3$ ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked for $n = 2$. To simplify the computation I tried setting $M = Id$ and so on the orthogonal complement, you get $vec(1_i1_i^T - e_i.e_i^T)$ where $1_i$ is a vector of all ones except one component with $-1$ and $e_i$'s form a standard basis. Thus, we get 2 linearly independent vectors on the orthogonal complement which is consistent with the rank of the space, i.e. 3. I think this should be generalized to higher dimension but still unclear at this point.

Comment: Also, another question is how to even generalize this to arbitrary matrices rather than just identity.

Comment: The idea works for $n = 3$ and subsequently for any dimension for $M = Id$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have made the edit. Also, my idea can be extended to diagonal matrices.

Comment: Thanks. Besides, I am puzzled by the fact that it is possible to take $z=0$ :  the problem looks simpler with matrices , resp. vectors of the form $yy^T$, resp. $vec(yy^T)$ : but may be, one can establish that this set cannot span the orthogonal space of vec(M) ?

Comment: In fact, I answer by the negative to my last suggestion : indeed, the set of matrices of the form $yy^T$ hasn't a sufficient span : for example in the case $n=3$; it has only dimension $6$ whereas we would need a dimension $8$...

Comment: Yeah, I think just $yy^T$ shouldn't span the orthogonal space, but I don't think dimensional argument works in the case of symmetric matrices as it is of dimension $\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Peliminary result : Let $(S_n)$ be the vector space of real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices. The set of all matrices of the form $xx^T-yy^T$ (which belong to $(S_n)$) generate
$(S_n)$.

General idea presented in the even case $n=2p$ (to be adapted for the case where $n$ is odd) presented in the case where all eigenvalue are distinct.

Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix.  $M$ is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues which can be either negative or positive.

By a suitable translation, $N=M-tI_n$, we can assume there are as many $<0$ or $\ge 0$ eigenvalues ; call them $-a_k$ and $b_k$ resp. with associated eigenvectors $U_k$ and $V_k$ resp.

Consider the diagonalization identity $N=ADA^T$ where $D=diag(-a_1 \cdots -a_p, b_1 \cdots b_p)$ and denoting the columns of $A$ by $U_1 \cdots U_p, V_1 \cdots V_p$.

This identity can be written :

$$N=\sum_{k=1}^p -a_k U_kU_k^T + \sum_{k=1}^p b_k V_kV_k^T$$

$$N=\sum_{k=1}^p -\underbrace{\sqrt{a_k} U_k}_{Y_k}\sqrt{a_k}U_k^T + \sum_{k=1}^p \underbrace{\sqrt{b_k} U_k}_{X_k}\sqrt{b_k}V_k^T$$

Otherwise said,

$$N=\sum_{k=1}^p (X_k X_k^T-Y_kY_k^T) $$

Now returning to $M=N+tI_n$, it suffices to write

$$I_n=uu^T-vv^T$$ with $v=\mathbb{1_n}$ and $u=\sqrt{2}v$ to complete the decomposition.

---

This preliminary result answers your question  : *yes* there is a basis of the orthogonal set **within $(S_n)$** constituted by matrices $xx^T-yy^T$ because these matrices generate $(S_n)$.

An "operational" example : let us consider the symmetric matrix

$$M=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\
           1&0&0\\
           0&0&0}$$

Its orthogonal space **within $(S_n)$** is the five-dimensional space of matrices :

$$M=\pmatrix{-2b&b&c\\
           b&d&e\\
           c&e&f}=b\underbrace{\pmatrix{-2&1&0\\
           1&0&0\\
           0&0&0}}_{M_b}+c\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&0&1\\
           0&0&0\\
           1&0&0}}_{M_c}+...+f\pmatrix{0&0&0\\
           0&0&0\\
           0&0&1}$$

Express each of the matrices $M_b,M_c,\cdots M_f$ as a linear combination of matrices $x_kx_k^T-y_ky_k^T$ (by the preliminary result) From this "first level" decomposition, reduce progressively this generating (surely over-abundant) set of matrices to a minimal number of elements (i.e., $5$)

Comment: I have modified my previous answer in order to reach "the" conclusion.

Comment: We are considering the space of symmetric matrices, right?

Comment: I thought we were in the ambient space of all $n \times n$ matrices. In this case the preliminary result (you don't say in your very  short comment if you have appreciated it) answers your question in a positive way. See my rectified answer

Comment: Sorry for the delayed message. Thanks for the preliminary result. What is missing/unclear here is that I'm looking for a basis for the orthogonal complement of $vec(M)$ such that each basis element, i.e. a vector of dimension $n^2$ has the desired form of $vec(yy^T - zz^T)$ for some $n$-dimensional vectors $y,z$. Thus, we are in the vector space of dimension $n^2$ induced by these symmetric matrices. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Well, I notice two issues with your solution: 1) although there is a spanning set it is not clear how to find a minimal set that forms a basis for the set of symmetric matrices and 2) the problem I asked (possibly misunderstood) was to find a basis of a specific form for the orthogonal complement. Just like $M$ needn't be written like $yy^T - zz^T$ (because of rank issue), it is not clear if one would find a basis of that form for the orthogonal complement to any symmetric matrix $M$.

Comment: About your first "issue" : an explicit basis shouldn't be difficult to find.